# If $f$ is nondecreasing and $h$ is of bounded variation with $|h(t)-h(s)|≤C\sqrt{f(t)-f(s)}$, then $\int|X||{\rm d}h|≤C\sqrt{\int|X|^2\:{\rm d}f}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, bounded-variation, stieltjes-integral

Let $f,g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb[0,\infty)$ be nondecreasing and right-continuous and $h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be right-continuous and of bounded variation with $$\left|h(t)-h(s)\right|\le\sqrt{f(t)-f(s)}\sqrt{g(t)-g(s)}\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge s\tag1.$$ Then it's well-known$^1$ that $$\int\left|XY\right|\left|{\rm d}h\right|\le\sqrt{\int|X|^2\:{\rm d}f}\sqrt{\int|Y|^2\:{\rm d}g}\tag2$$ for all Borel measurable $X,Y:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, where $|{\rm d}h|$ denotes the variation of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure induced by $h$.

> Now assume, instead of $(1)$, we've got $$\left|h(t)-h(s)\right|\le C\sqrt{f(t)-f(s)}\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge s\tag3$$ for some $C\ge0$. How can we use $(2)$ in order to conclude $$\int\left|X\right|\left|{\rm d}h\right|\le C\sqrt{\int|X|^2\:{\rm d}f}\tag4$$ for all Borel measurable $X:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$?

My first intuition was to simply set $g\equiv C$, but (obviously) that doesn't work since then the right-hand side of $(1)$ is $0$ and any integral with respect to ${\rm d}g$ is $0$. So, are we able to use $(2)$ at all or do we need to mimic its proof in order to establish $(4)$?

---

I don't know how this inequality is called in the nonrandom case, but in stochastic analysis this is the celebrated [Kunita-Watanabe inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunita%E2%80%93Watanabe_inequality).

Comment: It seems they have a common generalization: probably it holds with any (Borel) measure in place of $dg$. I would take a Dirac delta measure..

Comment: @Berci The generalization would be that $(1)$ holds for the measures on a generating semiring (for exaomple)? With Dirac delta measure, you mean at any point? But then $(1)$ might fail to hold. Could you describe what you mean in more detail?

Comment: @Berci Is this what you mean: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space, $\mu$ be a signed measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$, $\nu_i$ be a measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ and $\mathcal E\subseteq\mathcal A$ be $\cap$-stable with $\sigma(\mathcal E)=\mathcal A$ and $$|\mu(E)|\le\sqrt{\nu_1(E)}\sqrt{\nu_2(E)}\;\;\;\text{for all }E\in\mathcal E\tag5.$$ Then $$\int\left|XY\right|\:{\rm d}\mu\le\sqrt{\int|X|^2\:{\rm d}\nu_1}\sqrt{\int|Y|^2\:{\rm d}\nu_2}\tag6$$ for all Borel measurable $X,Y:\Omega\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Berci I could imagine that we're able to show this, but I don't see how you intend to choose $\nu_2$ as a Dirac measure.